# setting up package.json to deploy to heroku

Tags: heroku, package.json

I am trying to set up my package.json for deployment on heroku.

```
   {
  "name": "caffeine",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.12.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.4",
    "debug": "~2.1.1",
    "express": "~4.12.2",
    "express-session": "^1.11.3",
    "jade": "~1.9.2",
    "moment": "^2.10.3",
    "mongoose": "^4.0.2",
    "morgan": "~1.5.1",
    "node-phantom-simple": "^1.2.0",
    "passport": "^0.2.2",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-google-oauth": "^0.2.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^1.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.2.0",
    "should": "^6.0.3",
    "swig": "^1.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.11.0",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.29",
    "npm": "2.1.11"
  }
}
```

I am getting numerous errors. I started out by going through the trouble shooting on heroku  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys.  I am still getting the same errors though.  I went into my git ignore and added bower to it.  I added a procfile.  I know the error must me in my package, but I do not know what I am missing.

```
npm ERR! node v0.10.29
remote:        npm ERR! npm  v2.1.11
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! caffeine@0.0.0 postinstall: `bower install`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 127
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the caffeine@0.0.0 postinstall script 'bower install'.
remote:        npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the caffeine package,
```

Answer (score 0):

In my dev dependencies for package.json I am required to use

```
"bower": "1.4.1"
```

The message below explains what the heroku team notes.

```
    This error happens when you try running bower install after installing all you dependencies. However, bower isn't there.
You need to add it to your package.json so the executable is available to your app and you can execute that command.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in package.json file

```
 "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "client": "npm start -prefix client",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```